# Why do the metres seem to be increasing with frequency?

Tags: band-plan, arrl

I went to the ARRL's band plan site at https://clatsopauxcomm.org/index.php/technical/arrl-band-plan, and the first table began with the 60-metre band, which starts at 1.8MHz and ends at 2.0MHz. However, the next table shows the 80-metre band, which is 3.5 to 4.0MHz. This doesn't make sense. Shouldn't the wavelengths get shorter as frequencies increase?

Comment: Isn't it just a typo where it's missing a 1 at the start? It should read 160 metres.

Comment: @Buck8pe You should write that as an answer!

Comment: Not the question per se, but note that the site you linked is _not_ the ARRL's; this is: https://www.arrl.org/band-plan

Comment: I considered making it an answer, but decided on a comment since it reflects the effort I put in!

Comment: @Buck8pe Writing answers even when they're simple prevents questions from being listed as unanswered.

Comment: That's a fair point.  Next time;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is simply an error or typo on that website. Take a look at the companion color chart on that page that is provided by the ARRL. It shows that frequency range as 160 meters.

The formula for converting a frequency $f$, in MHz, to wavelength, $\lambda$, in meters is:

$$\lambda=300/f \tag 1$$

It is clear from inspection of the formula that wavelength is inversely related to frequency. So as frequency goes down, the wavelength increases.